# What are the differences of 3 time status in Linux file system

Tags: linux, file, time

I'm a fresh man in Linux.When learning the file system in Linux,I got confused with 3 kind of 3 time status,which are atime,ctime,mtime.What are they,how to distinguish them and what operation to files will cause their changing?

Comment: The very first link if I google for "mtime atime ctime" gives a very clear answer: http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/20526-mtime-ctime-atime.html

Comment: Access, creation, modification. But they're not necessarily reliable.

Comment: Despite the *You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)* auto-suggestion, I would think [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be the most appropriate place for this question.

Answer (score 3):

- atime: The last time the file was accessed
- ctime: The last time the inode was changed
- mtime: The last time the file data was changed

An [inode](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-speakingunix14/) is a collection of file metadata. While they can vary somewhat from filesystem to filesystem, a standard inode has the file's permissions, ownership, size, link count and a pointer structure indicating where the file's data reside on the disk. The inode doesn't contain actual file data and doesn't know the file's name, so the ctime is only updated when permissions, ownership, or links change for an inode.

Many filesystems will let you turn off some or all of these timestamps for performance reasons.